# How to allow location when using headless browser of cypress testing on event on click?

Tags: geolocation, cypress, headless-browser

### What I want to do

I want to integrate husky with the Cypress test when trying to commit some changes. So in my package.json file, there are two tests script

```js
"scripts": {
    "test:run": "./node_modules/.bin/cypress run",
    "test:open": "./node_modules/.bin/cypress open"
  },
```

##### The `test:open` is SUCCESS

[image]

##### But The `test:run` is FAIL

[image]

###### It says that `User has not allowed access to system location`

[image]

This is the function when Button "Godkänn" clicked in "Onboarding" page

```js
 const getDevicePermission = async () => {
    await getDeviceLocation().then(() =>
      getDeviceOrientation().then(() => Router.push(routes.ONBOARDING))
    );
  };
```

### What I've tried

1. Add configuration of browser permission in cypress.config.ts

```js
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  env: {
    browserPermissions: {
      notifications: "allow",
      geolocation: "allow",
    },
  },
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(_on, _config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },
});
```

The result is still FAIL with the same error

2. I've been following [this issue's solution](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2671https://) but still got the same error and no typescript support

Answer (score 2):

Add package [cypress-browser-permissions](https://github.com/kamranayub/cypress-browser-permissions)

```js
npm i cypress-browser-permissions --save-dev
//or
yarn install cypress-browser-permissions --save-dev
```

Update your `cypress.config.js`

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
const { cypressBrowserPermissionsPlugin } = require('cypress-browser-permissions')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  env: {
    browserPermissions: {
      notifications: "allow",
      geolocation: "allow",
    },
  },
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      config = cypressBrowserPermissionsPlugin(on, config)
      return config
    },
  },
})
```

---

**Testing**

To test, I used an app which essentially does this

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
```

With configuration `browserPermissions: { geolocation: "ask" }` the test throws up a permissions request dialog.

With configuration `browserPermissions: { geolocation: "allow" }` the test bypasses the dialog and the page displays the lat & long coordinates.

With configuration `browserPermissions: { geolocation: "block" }` the page shows "User denied the request for Geolocation." and the Cypress log shows the error

> (uncaught exception) undefined: User denied Geolocation

**App**

```html
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <div id="demo">Demo</div>
  <script>
    var demoDiv = document.getElementById("demo");

    function getLocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
      }
      else { demoDiv.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser."; }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
      var lat = position.coords.latitude;
      var lon = position.coords.longitude;
      demoDiv.innerText = `${lat} : ${lon}`
    }

    function showError(error) {
      demoDiv.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
      throw error
    }

    getLocation()
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I still got the error `undefined: User has not allowed access to system location`

Comment: Must be something in your app, it works ok for me.

Comment: Could you create a sample project with a cypress test based on the scenario above? It will be helpful if I can see the working example

Comment: Actually, I just tried to make it fail by removing the plugin, and it still worked. I'm just changing the app to match one of the samples, will let you know how it goes.

Comment: I forgot - this plugin affects browser launch options, so you can't just re-run the test you must restart the browser on each change.

Comment: I ran a more comprehensive test, and the plugins looks to be effective (running on Windows 10).

Comment: Awesome! could you create a reproducible code and put it in the public repository so I an access it?

Comment: Above is the full app, as mentioned key call is `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`. You would need to check that your app uses this call. (BTW Chrome browser).

Comment: Hm, I still got the erro. I wil try it again and will be back if works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you are running the tests on the test runner, you are running them on **Chrome**, And when running it on CLI you are running them on **Electron** browser. You can add the chrome browser for the `run` mode.

```js
"test:run": "./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --browser chrome"
```

To ignore exceptions generated from the application globally, you can add this in `cypress/support/e2e.js`

```js
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  // returning false here prevents Cypress from
  // failing the test
  return false
})
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for responding, now I got this error https://imgur.com/cRlHaJa. How I can set user to allow the location instead of denied it?

Comment: I could see in the test that there was an exception that was generated due to the user being denied the location. If you don't need the user location in your test, you can ignore this exception. Updated the answer.

Comment: But I need the user location in my test.